# How can I count notifications with FirebaseMessagingService?

Tags: android, notifications

I am developing a system that uses Notification push with Firebase. My problem is that I need to count the number of notifications and reset the counter ("contador" variable ) when the user clicks on them.

The function of the counter is to show the next message: "There are X new alarms".

After the first time that users receive notifications this counter doesn't increment and always show only 1 notification but it is possible that there may be more notifications.

Here is the code:

```
public class MiFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

   NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;

   int mNotificationId = 1234567;

   String titulo = "";

   int contador = 0;

   JSONArray alertas = new JSONArray();

  public static final String TAG = "NOTICIAS";

   @Override
   public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
       super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

       String from = remoteMessage.getFrom();

       Log.d(TAG, "Mensaje recibido de: "+from);

       if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Notificacion: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
           Log.d(TAG, "Zona:" + remoteMessage.getData().get("Zona").toString());

           contador++;
           Log.d(TAG, "Contador:" + contador);

           String cuerpo = "Se han detectado ".concat(String.valueOf(contador)).concat(" nuevas alarmas");
           titulo = titulo.concat(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle()).concat(",");

           JSONObject alerta_actual = new JSONObject();
           try {
               alerta_actual.put("Variable", remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle().toString());
               alerta_actual.put("Descripcion", remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody().toString());
               alerta_actual.put("Zona", remoteMessage.getData().get("Zona").toString());
               Log.d(TAG, "Alerta:" + alerta_actual.toString());

               alertas.put(alerta_actual);

               if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0)
               {
                   Log.d(TAG, "Data:"+remoteMessage.getData());
               }

               mostrarNotificacion(cuerpo);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

On the other hand, the code to show the message with the counter to the user is the next:

```
private void mostrarNotificacion(String body) {

    Log.d(TAG, alertas.toString());
    Log.d(TAG, "Contador:"+String.valueOf(contador));

    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int icono = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Notificaciones.class);
    i.putExtra("Alertas", alertas.toString());

    int uniqueInt = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0xfffffff);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, uniqueInt, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(icono)
            .setContentTitle(titulo)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    mNotifyMgr.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Why doesn't the counter "contador" increment after the first time?

Comment: it intialized every time on new instance of class,
you should store it in shaedPreferences